# Idle state(using ngIdle) of user is interrupting while silent refresh of access token from Identity server using Iframe in angular 5

Tags: iframe, angular5, identityserver4, refresh-token, ng-idle

How my Application works.

I am refreshing the token every 10 minutes from identity server using **Iframe**.
I am using **ngIdle** in my application to track the idleness of a User.

Call the refresh every 10 minutes

```
setInterval(() =>{
 this.refreshToken();
},100000);
```

Calling the URL using Iframe

```
refreshToken(){
let iframe =document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id ="refreshToken";
iframe.setAttribute('src',"/connect/tokenclient_id=client1& client_secret=secret&grant_type=authorization_code&code=hdh922&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/callback");
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```

If a user is Idle meanwhile silentrefresh gets called ,the idle time of the user gets interrupted and restarts.

I have tried hitting some other URLS from the iframe,but that didn't interrupt the idleness.It is happening only in identity server case

Comment: did you find out the root cause?